# NHibernate and many to many mapping

Tags: nhibernate, orm, mapping

I have 3 tables organization(id, name, and etc) organizationContact(organizationId, contactId, status)   contact(id, name, email)
How can I make a many to many mapping and use status column from organizationContact?

Answer (score 1):

For a strict many-to-many mapping, you would just have the organizationId and contactId in the mapping table. Adding the status column would require making a proper entity out of the organizationContact.